# I'm not sure how to solve the concept of finding a palindrome word using a while loop

Tags: javascript

Here is what I have coded so far. If I just please could have some guidance on ways to solve it better.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoA76.png)

Trying to define if a input is a palindrome or not . I know that I could use the reverse function ,but since they want me to use a while loop I'm overthinking some things. I've converted the input to lowercase and worked out the length. Then I create variables for the program to read the input from both sides in order to have the outcome of palindrome or not palindrome.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+palindrome+loop+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Looks like your `while` loop block does not have a closing curly bracket. This would normally give you a syntax error - if it wasn't for the fact that in this specific instance, the `if` block inside the loop doesn't have an _opening_ curly bracket either, so the overall count of opening and closing curly brackets still matches. Hint: _Everything_ coming after `//` on the same line, is commented out.

Comment: But the rest of it doesn't make much sense either - you are trying to respond based on the value of `wordIsAnPalindrome`, _before_ your while loop even determined what value that should have. (Btw., it is _a_ palindrome, not _an_.)

Comment: set right +=1   and left -=1 and then check your program

Comment: If you need to test a string, get rid of the white-space and non-characters and test each end: `const isPalindrome = str => { str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, ''); if (str === "") return false; for (let i = 0; i < str.length / 2; i++) { if (str[i] !== str[str.length - 1 - i]) return false; }
  return true; };`

Comment: Since it is a quite common problem, there could be answers somewhere on Internet, research first otherwise you will get negative response on the site

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend splitting up your logic:

1. Get input data
2. Sanitize input (convert to lowercase, remove whitespace …)
3. Pass sanitized input to your function

```js
const input = promt("Enter a word");
const sanitizedInput = input.toLowerCase().trim();

function isPalindrome(str) {
  let start = 0;
  let end = str.length - 1;

  while (start < end) {
    if (str[start] !== str[end]) {
      return false;
    }

    start += 1;
    end -= 1;
  }

  return true;
}

const result = isPalindrome(sanitizedInput);

result; // true | false
```

In your function, you need to initialize two pointers. One pointing to the start and one to the end.
You would check if the string at the start position is equal to the string position at the end. If not, you can early return and break out of the loop